# Клонирование модифицированной операционной системы

Tags: linux, altlinux

У меня есть root доступ к компьютеру на котором установлен модифицированный alt linux. Мне нужно склонировать эту модифицированную ос что бы можно было запускать её допустим у себя дома в virtual box

Как можно сделать образ загрузки системы linux?

Comment: Клонирование системы из-под самой системы — не очень хорошая идея, потому что в процессе клонирования какие-нибудь файлы могут измениться и сделать клон неконсистентным или вообще сломанным. Но если не жалко поэкспериментировать, то можно сделать копию файлов с помощью tar или rsync например. Ну и в целом https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_backup

Comment: Если есть возможность загрузить другую операционную систему (LiveCD или типа того), то можно склонировать весь системный раздел или вообще весь диск

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534501/how-to-clone-physical-system-into-a-virtual-machine

Comment: Берёшь `Clonezilla LiveCD`, делаешь образ, а дальше - разворачиваешь куда угодно.